# How to search HERE API for POI's by address, city, country, etc.?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoding, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am having trouble finding documentation or an example covering how to search for POI's within a certain radius of an address or location. So far, all I have seen is searching by latitude or longitude, which is not feasible in my use case.

The idea is a pretty standard one: a user enters a location (address, zip code, city, country, etc.) which leads to a call to the HERE API searching for a point of interest near the location that was entered. Perhaps within a certain radius.

Does anyone know how to use the HERE API to search by location, not coordinates? These are the dosc I am using: https://developer.here.com/documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's typical from location APIs to work with coordinates. For example, the *Discover* endpoint from [HERE Geocoding & Search API v7](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html) requires you to pass one of `at`, `in:bbox` or `in:circle` parameters, all of them working with coordinates.

What you need to do is to first convert your address to coordinates, by calling the *Geocode* endpoint.

**example of Geocoding using curl**

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?limit=20&q=2609 University Ave, Austin, TX 78712&apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY'
```

The above request returns the following response:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "2609 University Ave, Austin, TX 78712-1057, United States",
            "id": "here:af:streetsection:ihOI0ch5OPr-Y1e1m65IRC:CgcIBCDKhfpLEAEaBDI2MDk",
            "resultType": "houseNumber",
            "houseNumberType": "PA",
            "address": {
                "label": "2609 University Ave, Austin, TX 78712-1057, United States",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "countryName": "United States",
                "stateCode": "TX",
                "state": "Texas",
                "county": "Travis",
                "city": "Austin",
                "district": "University of Texas - Austin",
                "street": "University Ave",
                "postalCode": "78712-1057",
                "houseNumber": "2609"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 30.29009,
                "lng": -97.73891
            },
            "access": [
                {
                    "lat": 30.29009,
                    "lng": -97.73906
                }
            ],
            "mapView": {
                "west": -97.73995,
                "south": 30.28919,
                "east": -97.73787,
                "north": 30.29099
            },
            "scoring": {
                "queryScore": 1.0,
                "fieldScore": {
                    "state": 1.0,
                    "city": 1.0,
                    "streets": [
                        1.0
                    ],
                    "houseNumber": 1.0,
                    "postalCode": 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then use the coordinates returned by the *position* property of a response item to find Point of Interests around that location.